# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 exception in android for spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner

Hi in the below code for first time I am calling from Api and then storing in arraylist locally using Gson .

First time I am calling from api and second time calling from stored arraylist .Onitem selection it is throwing an error.when I am doing any item selection from the arraylist it is giving me arrayindexoutof bounds exception

can any one help me where I did the mistake

```
 if(!spinnertaskType.getHint().equals("")){
            final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, tinydb.getListString("taskTypeslist")) {// dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.borderdashboard.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                //spinnerlocation.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


                @Override
                public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                    if (position == 0) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                            ViewGroup parent) {
                    View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                    TextView tv = (TextView) view;

                    if (position + 1 == 0) {
                        // Set the hint text color gray

                        tv.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                    } else {
                        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    }
                    return view;
                }
            };
            // ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.borderdashboard.simple_spinner_item, taskTypes);
            spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnertaskType.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) spinnertaskType.getAdapter();
            int position = adapter.getPosition(task_types);
            spinnertaskType.setSelection(position + 1);

            spinnertaskType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//                                                        String selectedItemText = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    if (parent.getPositionForView(view)+1 > 0) {

                        PickListValues pickListValues = pickListTask.get(position);
                        task_type_value = pickListValues.getValue();

                        Toast.makeText
                                (getContext(), "Selected : " + task_type_value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();

                        Log.e("ids", task_type_value);
                        if (task_type_value.equals("Cold Call") || task_type_value.equals("Courtesy Call")) {
                            account.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            contact.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            outcomes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            opportunity.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        } else if (task_type_value.equals("Conference") || task_type_value.equals("Execution Documents") || task_type_value.equals("Training") || task_type_value.equals("Office Meeting")) {
                            account.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            contact.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            opportunity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            outcomes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        } else {
                            autoopportunity_name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            account.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            contact.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            outcomes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                }


                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });



        }
```

Comment: If you're getting an exception at `pickListTask.get(position)`, make sure `pickListTask` is not empty and it's size is more than the `position` you're trying to `get`

Comment: That error means the array your passing to the spinner is empty. So check your db method